# Changing logo image in header.php upon language detection

Tags: images, headers, language

So i'm designing a [website](http://www.europharmafuture.org) that will feature the Polylang plugin for automatic language detection, but I've run into a bit of a wall with the logo image. It resides in header.php, but I can't think of a way to develop a trigger to switch out that image when the browser detects a German visitor, etc.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, the only fix I can really think of is to export the logo image as code using Adobe Illustrator CC, which I don't have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to create a new logo for every single language? Can you not make the text in the logo HTML, it doesn't look like a complex graphic. Also, ignore the first post in [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-polylang-return-the-current-language-as-variable-for-your-template) but the post by the author and the one below it might be helpful. (I say ignore the first post becuase it sounds like they're editing the plugin files directly which you should never do!)

The code looks like this:

```
<div>
    <?php
        $currentlang = get_bloginfo('language');
        if($currentlang=="en-US"):?>
            This is English
        <?php else: ?>
            This is not English
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

by User [ChowKaiDeng](http://wordpress.org/support/profile/chowkaideng)